# Unable to communicate between docker and external service

Tags: node.js, docker, api, networking, request

I have a docker container running in localhost:3000

Also, I have a node app running in localhost:8081

Now if I want to make post or get request from localhost:3000 to localhost:8001 its not working at all.

Now if run the service as a binary (not a docker file) on localhost:3000 the same API requests works.

How do I communicate if using docker?

Comment: How many different `localhost`s are there?  (Each container is typically its own `localhost`, and if the two containers are running on separate systems, you have at least four different meanings of `localhost`.)

Answer (score 0):

Each container runs on it's own bridge network where `localhost` means the container itself.

To access the host, you can add the option `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` to the `docker run` command. Then you can access the host using the host name `host.docker.internal`. I.e. if you have a REST service on the host, your URL would look something like `http://host.docker.internal:8081/my/service/endpoint`.

The name `host.docker.internal` is the common name to use for the host, but you can use any name you like.

You need docker version 20.10 for this to work.

Comment: both are not containers, port 3000 is docker container, 8081 is just a standalone node app (not dockerized) @hans

Comment: appreciate it, but if I understood correctly, your answer explains the opposite scenario, i need to connect nodeapp (make post or get request) from my docker container, i need my node app to be accessible from docker.

Comment: You add the option to the container. When you do that, it can access the node app on `http://host.docker.internal:8081/my/service/endpoint` from inside the container.

Comment: Can I do that using docker-compose can you please help me with the config yaml file

Comment: If you want to use docker-compose, I think you should see how far you can get and then make a new question